# Complex integration problem?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, parametric, complex-integration

Compute the integral
$$\int_{C}\cos\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\,dz$$
Where

$C : γ(t) := ${$t + i\sqrt{π^2 − t^2}, −π ≤ t ≤ π$}

Not quite sure about how to go about doing this one, usually I parameterised and it became easy.

Answer (score 2):

The cosine function is an entire function.

Hence, the value of the integral depends only on the end points of the curve $C$.  When $t=-\pi$, $z=-\pi$ and when $t=\pi$, $z=\pi$.

Therefore, we can write

$$\int_C \cos(z/2)\,dz=\left.\left(2\sin(z/2)\right)\right|_{z=-\pi}^{z=\pi}=4$$